# Cannot read props in child when using Dialog component

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

Component can not access props when used in Primevue Dialog component.

I don't know if this is a bug in Primevue or if it's me who's doing something general wrong in Vue3. When structured like this, the prop "user" doesn't get the value from selectedUser.

But if I move  outside of the Dialog component everything works as expected.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    <Dialog 
      v-model:visible="showUserModal" 
      modal
      :header="modalUserTitle" 
      :style="{ width: '50vw' }"
      :draggable="false"
      :hide="selectedUser = null"
    >    
      <TabView>
        <TabPanel :header="$translate('user')">
          <TestComponent :user="selectedUser" />
        </TabPanel>
      </TabView>  
    </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have prop :hide on ur dialog, but it's not prop it is emit, u can check it here [DIALOG EMITS](https://primevue.org/dialog/#api.dialog.emits). What u need to do, is change :hide to @hide and everithing should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but that's not the problem. 
When I open the dialog, I assign data to the variable selectedUser.
But when I have <Testcomponent /> inside of the primevue Dialog, the prop "user" doesn't work. (I have a watcher in the component, and as I wrote, everything works when Testcomponent is moved outside of the dialog component.

Comment: If i understood correctly, this is the problem, because when u writing :hide="Something here" something here is a fucntion which called everytime dialog is mounted. In ur case selectedUser = null. Codepen : https://codesandbox.io/s/primevue-demo-forked-3l3v9l?file=/src/App.vue. Maybe i missed something and u can show ur TestComponent code either.

Comment: Thanks for your time, something else in the code was breaking it without throwing an error, when I redid everything it worked as expected. But thanks for your help!